# problem with dual horizontal scroll view touches

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, hittest, touchesbegan

I've been dealing with this problem for weeks, and still no solution. please help.

I have a big scroll view with images. each image is screen wide, and paging enabled.

on this scroll view, in the bottom, i have another scroll view with button. each button for each image. when i push the image button, the big scroll view jump to the image.

since i have a lot of images, i have a lot of buttons on the little scroll view.

right now, the big scroll and small scroll are working ok, and the buttons also.

my problem start at the far ends of the little scroll. when i'm in the end of the little scroll (but still in the middle of the big one) i don't want the big one to move when i move my finger to the dead end. you can say i want to separate the small scroll from the big one, but still leave him as a subview (because i want it to move with the big one).

i've tried subclassing the little scroll, the buttons, override hitTest and touchesBegan/End but nothing so far.

i'm realy realy frustrated because my costumer demands this to work his way.

i've been googled for so long and i can't find anything!

HELLLPPPPP!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a piece of code that I found to be invaluable in one of my projects:

```
- (UIView*)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UIView* result = [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];

    if (/* result or any of its superviews are equal to your little scroll view */) {
        [self setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:YES];
        self.scrollEnabled = NO;
    } else {
        self.scrollEnabled = YES;    
    }
    return result;
}
```

If I understood your question correctly I think this will give you the desired behavior. I have some pseudo code in the if statement (the comment), since going through all the superviews would require looping, which would make the code much more complicated, but if you're familiar with your view hierarchy you can often find a simpler solution.

I hope this helps and if you're having any trouble understanding the code I'll be happy to give you an explanation.

**EDIT:** The basic idea is that you turn of scrolling in the big scroll view if your finger is touching the little scroll view, so that the big scroll view won't scroll. If your finger isn't touching the little scroll view, the scrolling of the big scroll view is turned back on and should behave as normal.

Comment: should i put it in the big scrollview subclass or in the mainview subclass?

Comment: The big scroll view subclass. Sorry for not being clear about that.